# Display product with price down in custom module

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I would like to find out what I'm doing wrong. I created a module and in the getContent () function I wanted to display products that have a discount, I used that

$products = Product::getPricesDrop((int)$this->context->language->id, 0, 10);﻿﻿﻿

The problem is that it gets Notice in line 2376 in C: \ wamp64 \ www \ xxxxx \ classes \ Product.php [8] Trying to get property of non-object

I do it in the module.php file

Comment: That method calls another static method which uses `$context->customer->id_default_group` and `customer` object is not available in backend.

Comment: so, what I can display all products? problem exists ony if debug is true